# Appraisal Cycle

Tags: performance-reviews, appraisal

Many companies have their annual appraisal & pay hike once a year at a fixed time. Let's say for a company it happens in January of every year.

How are employees who join at different times handled. For e.g. if there is an employee who joined in September, then Jan may be too soon for an appraisal & a hike. However, if it is skipped totally, then his first appraisal would be 16 months after he joined. How is this handled?

Comment: Usually, exactly as you said there, they wait 16 months

Comment: This is off topic, as it's simply a company-specific policy.  At my workplace, there is a set policy where you have to have been there X months before that point to get a raise.

Comment: And at my company, you get a review and a pay hike, but it's pro-rated for the percent of the year that you've been working. Been working 6-months? If your performance merits a 4% raise, your actual raise is 2%. Same with bonuses.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, at least in my experience, every employee will have a review on the date of the review cycle regardless of when they start.

If the employee is brand spanking new they may not get a raise, but they will get a feel for how the process works and if the employee is smart, they can get a firm understanding of their managers expectations.

If they have been with the company long enough ( partial first year employee ) they will typically get a partial raise, if earned.  ( something, but not the amount they would get had they been an employee for the full year )